# How to set up a specific registration on Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a database so that I can access names of people from a university. But I would like to create a registration ID for each person (like 1012607) of which the first 2 numbers would be the year (11 for 2011) and the third digit would be the semester they registered (1 in the beginning of the year and 2 in the end of the year).

The other 4 digits would be incremental. I don't know how to code a prefixed number in MySQL that can change only the last 4 digits and after a year change the first 2 digits every time you have a new registration. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Are you writing an application that utilizes the database, or are you only designing the database?  Normally I would expect logic like this to be handled by the application, not directly in the db.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is it an intellectual exercise? Or is it to integrate with some existing system? I try and avoid this sort of thing at call costs, it's a big tin of pink tubular invertebrates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you have a table design like the following:

```
ID - auto increment Identity(1000,1)
Year - date
Semester - int
```

then when reporting on it use the logic you mentioned above. Doesn't have to be that complicated.

Comment: can i create a procedure or function to do that?

Comment: sure why not. Create a table with 3 columns like i mentioned above then just create a stored procedure that just combines Year + Semester + ID columns to give you what you want.

Comment: Or you could just add DateRegistered, key the table with an Auto inc, and then write a function to build the 'intelligent' number from the date based stuff, and the last four digits of the id, padded with leading zeros if required. Gives you a surrogate key as well, win, win and win.